# What is User Token useful for ?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

There is an article here:
http://alt.pluralsight.com/wiki/default.aspx/Keith.GuideBook/HowToGetATokenForAUser.html

It's not clear why I would need it ? Is it for ASP.NET or also Winform ?

Comment: There's a link in the document you linked to that provides the answer: http://alt.pluralsight.com/wiki/default.aspx/Keith.GuideBook/WhatIsAToken.html

Answer (score 0):

If you need information about the current user or some other user on the system, then yes it is useful.  If you don't, then it isn't.

It's like asking why one would need the + operator.  Either you need to do addition, and it is useful, or you don't, and it isn't.

Comment: A token is not the current user name as I read "A token is a kernel object that caches part of a user's security profile" so why would I need a "kernel object" ?